# Get current user data from Parse.com using android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm creating a app and I need to separate the user from the admin's when they try to log in. The admin's have a data on the Parse Server that always return a String value (is an information that they put on the register), but the regular users will always return null on the value of this String. My idea is to get the information of this String, if she returns null it means that is a regular user, if returns something, means it is a admin, so they go to different activities. I'm having problem on the code to get this info from Parse, how can I get a current user data from Parse, maybe using getQuery, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("customFieldKey")` to get values of custom fields of your ParseUser object.